# Get Azure Devops Pipeline Step Runtimes

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Looking through the Azure Devops APIs it appears like it isn't possible to get the runtime of individual steps in a pipeline run?

[Pipeline steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqQ3D.png)

I'm looking to scrap the runtime of each step in a pipeline run across all runs of a pipeline.

I've looked at the Azure Devops APIs, and while I see how to get pipeline run details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), it doesn't appear like the API includes step level information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Timeline - Get` REST API to achieve the runtime of individual steps in a pipeline run. Please refer to doc:[Timeline-GET-REST APT](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fbuild%2Ftimeline%2Fget%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-rest-5.1%23timelinerecord&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7Cce42c2a232e5425b22ce08dacb7f335b%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638046044437520192%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=Wn6jdziwrfw6pHGcchTRzJM%2Bp%2FC%2BUNKRWleMIG9UPlQ%3D&reserved=0)

For example:

URL

```
  GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline/{timelineId}?api-version=5.1
```

Test in postman:
[image: detail of build]

The response body returns a list of build details that include job/step/task `type` and `name` and `startTime` and `finishTime` according timeline.